# Export data to excel by creating instance of the Excel.Application object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

Currently i'm using ImportExcel module to fetch data from multiple csv file and export in single excel file. But due to network restriction from this month I am not able to install importexcel module. Is there is any way i can use excel without importing/installing any module.

Reference Site: -  Visit https://learn-powershell.net/2012/12/20/powershell-and-excel-adding-some-formatting-to-your-report/

After mutliple search on internet i found something like below but showing error at line 26.

```
$ExcelObj = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$ExcelObj.visible=$False
$Myworkbook = $Myexcel.workbooks.add()
$Sheet1 = $Myworkbook.worksheets.item(1)
$Sheet1.name = "OverAll"
$Sheet1.Range("A1:F1").font.size = 18
$Sheet1.Range("A1:F1").font.bold = $true
$Sheet1.Range("A1:F1").font.ColorIndex = 2
$Sheet1.Range("A1:F1").interior.colorindex = 1

$destPath = "\\192.168.90.12\Data\"

$Results = Get-ChildItem $destPath -Recurse -Include '*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{

        SerialNumber = $_.BaseName
        
    }
    Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName | ForEach-Object {
        $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $_.Parameter -Value $_.Status -Force
    }
    $Object
}

 $Results | Select-Object SerialNumber,ComputerName, Antivirus, Firewall,GoogleChrome, MicrosoftEdge |
$Myfile = "C:\Temp\OverAll.xlsx"
$Myexcel.displayalerts = $false
$Myworkbook.Saveas($Myfile)
$Myexcel.displayalerts = $true
$Myworkbook.Close()
 $Excelobj.Quit()  
 [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelObj)
```

Comment: Yes, using Excel COM as you are. Yet, you are really overcomplicating this. Excel reads CSV's natively, then you just need to save it as XLS. Simply put, use the normal text file feature in cmdlet, merge the CSV file data, open the CSV in XLS and save it as an XLS file type.

Comment: @postanote want to color the cell based on text and range.

Comment: You can do that after the initial save as a true XLS. So, you take the approach I already mention, then not close the workbook, apply any further updates to the worksheet, then save and close it.

Comment: @Postanote How to do that. I have no idea.

Comment: Again, the are lots of examples like or better than this one all over there web, right here on SuperUser and on Youtube. The reason you are getting the error on line 26 is because of the errant pipe character at the end of the line. If you open this script in the PowerShell ISE or VSCode, you'll see the error indicator for $MyFile, and look at the previous line. You can have that pipe character there because it is not piping anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***That line 36 error is because of this...***

```
$Results | Select-Object SerialNumber,ComputerName, Antivirus, Firewall,GoogleChrome, MicrosoftEdge |
$Myfile = "C:\Temp\OverAll.xlsx"
```

***It should be this:***

```
$Results | Select-Object SerialNumber,ComputerName, Antivirus, Firewall,GoogleChrome, MicrosoftEdge
$Myfile = "C:\Temp\OverAll.xlsx"
```

[All the below samples are just items discoverable on the web, on SU, or on Youtube.](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell%20%27%27Converting%20CSV%20to%20Excel%20File%27&t=h_&ia=web)

You can practice getting the idea of Excel COM with something as simple as this:

```
$FileName = "$env:temp\Report"

# create some CSV data
Get-Process | 
Export-Csv -Path "$FileName.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8


# load into Excel
$excel         = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application 
$excel.Visible = $true

# change thread culture
[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 'en-US'

$excel.Workbooks.Open("$FileName.csv").SaveAs("$FileName.xlsx",51)
$excel.Quit()

explorer.exe "/Select,$FileName.xlsx"
```

***Messing with color:***

```
#requires -Version 2.0
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

# accessing excel via COM
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
# # make it visible (for debugging only, can be set to $false later in production)
$excel.Visible = $true

# add workbook
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()

# access workbook cells
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1,1) = 'Hey!'

# formatting cell
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1,1).Font.Size = 20

$r = 200
$g = 100
$b = 255

[System.Drawing.ColorTranslator]::ToOle([System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(255,$r,$g,$b))
$workbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(1,1).Font.Color = $r + ($g * 256) + ($b * 256 * 256)

# saving workbook to file
$Path = "$env:temp\excel.xlsx"
$workbook.SaveAs($Path)
```

***See more here:***

[Converting CSV file or files into an Excel workbook](https://learn-powershell.net/2010/09/04/converting-csv-file-or-files-into-an-excel-workbook/)